# How to clone a specific Git branch from local git server

Tags: git

I have a shared network directory that contains git repositoiry objects

```
\\@ip\git\test-app
```

In the `refs/heads` i can see my branche called `branche-test`

so I want to clone this branche using git

so I use this commande

```
git clone --progress --branch branche-test -v "\\@ip\git\test-app"
```

This command still blocked not work and there's no error message I ask if this error could be a right access problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your command should work from git bash console. Try to test if file path is ok?
`git clone --progress --branch branche-test -v "//@ip/git/test-app"`

Answer (score 0):

If it's on Windows, the shared repository should have been assigned a drive letter, `M` for example. In git-bash, you can access the remote repository by `/m/git/test-app`.

```
git clone --progress --branch branche-test -v /m/git/test-app
```